Angular: ng build not putting components in dist folder
I've build an angular application which is working as expected with ng serve.
When using ng build, i get the project in the dist file. But all the components are missing. I only get the images folder from the assets, and files like the index.html, main.js, polyfill.js etc. But all my component folders are missing.
In a previous project i did get all the files with ng build. I am not getting an error when using ng build.
This is my angular.json:


"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "wwna3kannenapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/kannenapp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          ],
          "server": "src/main.server.ts",
          "prerender": true,
          "ssr": {
            "entry": "server.ts"
          }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "5MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "10kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "wwna3kannenapp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "wwna3kannenapp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }



Pasted it as a snippet as it would not let me paste it correctly as a code block.
This is the content of my dist folder:

My package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^18.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
"firebase": "^10.13.1",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.14.3"

},
How do i resolve this and get a complete build in my dist folder?

This is totally normal when you are building an application. Maybe the previous project was a library? As far as I can tell everything works as expected. What are you trying to do with the built components?

This is because all of your components are in main.js or chunks.

@BojanKogoj, and why is this te case? As it was not in my previous project. When opening the index.html in the browser I get an empty page and 404's for missing files

Did you migrate to esbuild? Btw you can use "namedChunks": true, in angular.json

Not really an expert. But i only made a new project with ng new projectname. Same versions as the previous project. I did not migrate or update anything.

Previously, build was launched by default with development configuration. Now this is launched by default with production configuration.
Production configuration applies several build optimizations, including: Bundling files, Minimizing excess whitespace, Removing comments and dead code, Minifying code to use short mangled names. Production code makes the code less human readable and is what you see now. This is totally normal and is the recommanded behavior for deploying your files.
https://angular.dev/reference/configs/workspace-config#alternate-build-configurations
https://angular.dev/cli/build
You must have been working on an old project, as this behavior has been changed since angular v12-14
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/20128
If needed for your local developments, you can still get the other behavior with ng build --configuration development

Thanks. My previous application was angular 18. The same for this one. The previous has all the components as a folder in the dist. This one does not. They both work though.. this application did not work because of a mistake in the paths and base href. But i still dont understand why the previous application gives all the components in the dist and this one does not.

If you have still access to your old app code, you should take a look at its angular json. They must have changed the default build configuration to put the development one, or changed the parameters of the production one, which is used by default

@Pvangerrevink, you need a "server" to "run" the app, not only a navigator (in the navigator address should appear some like http://localhost:4200/, not file:///C:/....

If you're using Visual studio code you can "run" select index.html
with the right button of mouse and use open with Live server

Others IDEs have a similar option.

You can also use the lite-server.
Here there are a "step-by step" to install if it's not clear
the installation in the first link.


